# Mail client with read/accesslock for mails

Tags: collaboration, email-client

I'm looking for a collab mailclient (web or windows) that can be used for accessing one mail account with different persons.

We want that software to indicate that a mail is accessed and so the other persons working on the same mail account would not be abled to open that specific mail too.